# how to move call log number or message to my app and remove from the default call log or message log

Tags: android, android-phone-call

Hi friends i am making the privacy app where i am storing some private numbers in the realm database when ever call comes the number which exists in the db then it must not visible in the default call log but it must be stored in my app where it same goes to SMS when every message come from that number the message must be stored in the app not in the default messaging log i am using broadcast receiver to know about the number but i am not able to understand how to move call log or message to my app please help me out friends

Comment: In order to change the call log, you will have to convince your users to use your app instead of the normal phone app.

Comment: thank u i will do that